# size not shown for selected files

Tags: windows-7

When I select a file or more it doesn't show the size, only the date modified. Is there a problem or it's not implemented, or can I modify this. I would like to see the size of the selected files.

Thanks

Comment: if I select more than 15 files or a directory it says "show more details" and when I click on it... nothing happens, or it shows Date modified...

Comment: you're not the only one, there are a couple of posts here already complaing about it. Microsoft has removed this feature from the status bar due to ... "User Anxiety" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feature removed by Microsoft :(

(http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/7b7058e4-4ed2-4897-bad2-fd1dc71769db)

Comment: If you think this is the answer to your question you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on any of the selected files and then click "Properties", it'll show you the size of them.

I get the same issue with "Show more details", but only if there are folders included in my selection. I assume that Windows 7 does this so that it doesn't have to traverse a folder hierachy in order to show the size of it.

Comment: vista shows only the size of the folders, it doesn't recursive search in the selected folders...